# Story about a time traveller who became their own mother and father

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I once read about a story in which, by a series of unlikely manoeuvres of time travel and a sex change operation, one person (originally a girl) managed to **be her own mother and father**. IIRC, she was brought up in an orphanage, travelled back in time to father a child (herself) with a near-stranger in a bar, then later became a man and travelled back in time to impregnate a near-stranger (him/herself) in a bar.

Unfortunately, because I only heard *about* the story and never actually read it, I have no idea whether it's a novel or short story, when and in what language it was written, what it looked like, etc. Hopefully the plotline will be distinctive enough to enable someone to find it!

Comment: Well, wow! Three answers all within 4 seconds of each other :-O

Comment: I promise I did not use time travel.

Comment: @Mike Plot twist: all three answerers are actually the same person!

Comment: For the record, now that I know the author and title, I could easily find the place I'd heard of it before: http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/12894/all-you-zombies

Comment: _All You Zombies_ is the only time paradox story you'll ever need to read.  Heinlein retired the trophy.  There's never been any need to write another.

Comment: Though that's only for the category "serious time travel stories".  For "humorous time travel stories" there's one of Pirx the Pilot's voyages (by Lem) that takes the prize.  I forget which voyage ... but you'll know it when you read it.

Comment: (Oh fudge! It wasn't Pirx the Pilot.  It was a Tale of Ijon Tichy! Also by Lem.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like the *movie* [Predestination](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2397535/), which is also based on a novel (see other answers).

The main character, a time traveler, is revealed to be a hermaphrodite. A  Barkeep meets a man, John, that reveals that he was raised in an orphanage and *as a girl*. She had a child with a man she knew, but disappeared from her life.

The child, the Barkeep, John and Jane are all the same person, at different points in their own timeline.

So, the woman didn't meet a man she barely knew in a bar and have a child with them, but there is a main plot point about the character meeting a man in a bar.

This timeline image shows the loop of their life, plus their other identity:

> [image]

Comment: I spent a whole minute thinking "Barkeep" was an Indian name ... definitely time for bed. Upvotes all round!

Comment: @randal'thor Sorry. I capitalized it because in the discussions around the movie, which are man, that's the "name" given to the character, as evidenced by the image. Get some sleep!

Answer (score 11):

['—All You Zombies—'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies)  is a short story written by Robert Heinlein. It has also been made into a movie [Predestination](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination_(film)).

Comment: And arguably the greatest time travel story ever. Possible rivals Primer and Coherence

Comment: I was running circles when I watched Primer.

Answer (score 5):

It's Robert Heinlein's *All You Zombies*, published in 1959.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/All_You_Zombies